# I've 6 queries in mysql which I need to execute using php all at once. How can I do it.?

Tags: php, mysql

I've a multiple SQL Queries which together create a pivot table. Now I want to run this query using PHP. I tried running it using PDO but it returns an error.

This is PHP code that I wrote

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "logs";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    die($ex->getMessage());
}

$query = "start transaction;
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 5000;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
        'MAX(IF(cropname = ''',
        cropname,
        ''', quantity, NULL)) AS ''',
        cropname,''''
    )
) INTO @sql
FROM
    tempcrop;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT date, SUM(quantity),', @sql, ' FROM tempcrop Group By date');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    commit;";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

$cropData = array();

while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $cropData['AllCrops'][] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($cropData);
```

Running this code give me an error

> 'Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error'

How can I run these queries instead?

Comment: is tthe error from your connection? or the transaction start?

Comment: Solved it using **mysqli_multi_query**.

Comment: multi_query is usually a bad idea, but your life.

Comment: **DO NOT USE** `mysqli_multi_query`. This doesn't run queries "at once", it runs them sequentially and *completely ignores any error conditions that arise*. You want to run them one by one and *check the result of each execution before proceeding*.

Comment: There's also no need for this process of declaring a stored procedure and then running it once. Just run the query. Don't mess around with stored procedures unless you have a very compelling reason, and most of the time what you need is a `VIEW` instead.

Comment: It's also a huge step backwards from PDO to `mysqli`.